# Update data to Mysql in a while loop with Python: Only partial data was saved

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using python to connect to mysql and write data to a table. I have a while loop, and I update one particular row of the table with some values in each loop. Then after the loop ends, I commit the execution. Now the problem is: I should have 5000 rows of data updated since there are 5000 loops. However, I only see 1K rows or of data update. Following is the pseudo-code:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
connection =pymysql.connect(
            user='root',
            host='localhost',
            database='mysql')
mycursor=connection.cursor()
mycursor.execute('use test_db')

n=0
while n<5000:
  id=IDlist[n]
  url='www.example.com/'+str(id)
  values=requests.get(url) ##some parse omitted
  input=(values[1],values[2],id)
  sql="""UPDATE mytable
         SET COL1=%s, COL2=%s
         WHERE ID=%s"""
  mycursor.execute(sql, input)

connection.commit() ## here all loops done
```

The following is the structure of the table:

[ID INT(5) NOT NULL, COL1 VARCHAR, COL2 MEDIUMBLOB]

where column ID is the PRIMARY KEY

So basically what I do is: I read a unique id each time, go to the corresponding webpage and read some data values then write the values in the row corresponding to that unique id.

My concern is that, could it be possible that since data to be saved is relatively large (~500KB) in each loop, so some data just lost during while loop before connection.commit() was made?

If this were the case, then should I declare auto commit beforehand? However, it seems that executing auto-commit right after data is inserted/updated in each loop will cause the whole task to be relatively slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider breaking up the requests and MySQL update. You can iteratively append lists in a large `input[]` list. Then, iterate through `input[]`. Notice I move all opening of database connection and cursor toward the end to minimize long connection times. Also, you want to commit after each execute so commit should be inside the loop.

```
import pymysql

# URL DATA 
input = []  ## LIST OF LISTS
for id in IDlist:
     url='www.example.com/'+str(id)
     values=requests.get(url) ##some parse omitted
     input.append([values[1],values[2],id])

# DATABASE UPDATE
connection = pymysql.connect(
            host='localhost', db='test_db',
            user='root', passwd='***')
mycursor = connection.cursor()

for items in input:
     sql="""UPDATE mytable
         SET COL1=%s, COL2=%s
         WHERE ID=%s"""
     mycursor.execute(sql, tuple(items))    
     connection.commit() 

mycursor.close()  ## here all loops done
connection.close()  ## close db connection
```

Comment: Thank you very much Parfait. Creating a whole list to be saved at the end is more straightforward and clear. However what makes me hesitate using it is that any interruption (e.g., interruption to the server) will cause data (that has been retrieved from web and stored in the input list) lost. That's why I was considering using auto commit, or at least commit every hundreds of loops. In your experience, which way is the best when you have a large and sequential data to read and to save? Construct a long list of data then save at the end or auto-commit?

Comment: My real task (the one I asked in my original question was only for testing) will include requesting ~50K pages and read data about ~5 mega bytes from each then save all of them into my database. So the volume of data is what I'm worried about...

Comment: Try it in batches, maybe every 5,000 pages import into db, clean out list, retrieve next 5,000 pages. Plug your machine to hard-wired ethernet line and let program run all night. If you run into a connection disruption, note the last page parsed on and continue from there. Just don't have database cursor open and wait until request is made and values retrieved as it can timeout, requiring re-connection.